# Google Static Maps only shows map briefly after viewing it in a different browser tab

Tags: google-maps-static-api

I'm building a rails app, and attempting to put multiple Google Static Maps into the view.  These maps will always display broken-image placeholders, except it works when I:

-Use firebug to grab the src URL for the map image
-Paste the URL into another browser tab
-Refresh my apps page with the Google static maps
-I can then view a static map for the URL I pasted, but no others, and only for about 1 min.

Any map on the page I repeat this procedure for will then be viewable, for about 1 minute.  Then after about 1 min, that map will revert to a broken image placeholder if I refresh the page.

An example URL from my app (without my API Key) is:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Paris%2C+France&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false&markers=color:blue|label:A|Paris%2C+France

Paste (or click) this into your browser, and you see it works.  I paste this URL *WITH my API key in it* into my browser, it works & and my app will show the static map for a limited time, and then after that it will be broken again.  If I paste a URL *without my API key*, this procedure doesn't work.  It's like viewing the map in another browser tab somehow caches it momentarily in my browser, and it will then work in my app... but then it will break in a minute.  Haven't found any other way to make map images viewable.

Any ideas why this would happen?

EDIT:

This is extremely strange.  In an attempt to diagnose this, I did a copy/paste/save of the apps page source containing the broken map images, and put it on a remote server out in the World.  In this new totally static page, I got the same result: I see broken placeholder images where the google map pic should be.  But after I copy the src URL of the image & paste it in another browser tab, I can go back to the static page, refresh & only that map image appears.

Stranger still (maybe?), it shows up on my localhost app too.  It also shows up on a static local copy/paste of the app page source I save as an HTML file.

So, not saying this *must* be it, but it seems to be a browser caching issue.  No matter where the view page is represented, whether local or remote, and no whether it is dynamically generated or static HTML, the original behavior remains the same.

Comment: Solved:  I put in an API key that allowed any referer to respond to the request.  I had set this to the hosts I was working on, but doing away with that restriction (against Googles own advice (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?hl=nl#quick_example) "We strongly recommend that you restrict the use of your key to domains that you administer...") made it work.  So it is *solved*, but not optimally.

Comment: I had the same issue. I'm also using the same method to fix it. It seems Google is having an issue with the referrer. I whitelisted the server IP, the company domain as well as my domain and were still having issues.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not considering that the referrer is the one who shows the static map. Check these examples:

1. Static map shown in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/styling?hl=nl: the referrer is https://developers.google.com
2. You grab this link (that is already in the url of the URL on bullet 1) https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=512x512&zoom=15&center=Brooklyn&style=feature:road.local%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0x00ff00%7Cweight:1%7Cvisibility:on&style=feature:landscape%7Celement:geometry.fill%7Ccolor:0x000000%7Cvisibility:on&style=feature:administrative%7Celement:labels%7Cweight:3.9%7Cvisibility:on%7Cinverse_lightness:true&style=feature:poi%7Cvisibility:simplified&key=YOUR_API_KEY and you paste it in your browser: the referrer is YOUR PUBLIC IP.

So it's normal if the link does not work in any browser but it works in a determined web page. This happens when the authorized referrer is only the host of the web.

Consider also that you may be hitting the free limits of displays per day.